# IF statements within .HTMLBody

Tags: html, vba, if-statement, iif

Users will input answers through a userform, then an email summary of the responses will be sent. Several questions in the userform are optional.

In the .HMTLBody section, I would like certain responses to be emailed in red text if they were answered (they normally aren't, so I want it to be easy to spot).

Is there a way to use a conditional statement to format certain fields within the .HTMLBody section? (IIF?)

Sample below ("Business Unit" field optional).

Thank you.

```
Dim EmailBody as String

EmailBody = "Unit Name: " & UCase(Me.ttbUnitName.Value) & “<br>” _
    & "Nation: " & UCase(Me.cbxNation.Value) & “<br>” _
    & "State: " & UCase(Me.cbxState.Value) & “<br>” _
    & "County: " & UCase(Me.cbxCounty.Value) & “<br>” _
    & "Business Unit: " & UCase(Me.ttbBusinessUnit.Value)

   With MItem
        .To = "123@fake.com"
        .CC = myEmail
        .DeferredDeliveryTime = SendAt
        .Subject = Me.Name & " Submission"
        .HTMLBody = EmailBody
   End With
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.HTMLBody` is just a string(which is expected to be HTML). You can use `if` while building that string.

So you can use a construct like this

```
Dim EmailBody as String

EmailBody = "Unit Name: " & UCase(Me.ttbUnitName.Value) & “<br>” _
    & "Nation: " & UCase(Me.cbxNation.Value) & “<br>” _
    & "State: " & UCase(Me.cbxState.Value) & “<br>” _
    & "County: " & UCase(Me.cbxCounty.Value) & “<br>”
    if Me.ttbBusinessUnit.Value <> "" then 'or whatever condition you have
       EmailBody = EmailBody & "<font color=""red"">Business Unit: " & UCase(Me.ttbBusinessUnit.Value) & "</font>"
    end if

   With MItem
        .To = "123@fake.com"
        .CC = myEmail
        .DeferredDeliveryTime = SendAt
        .Subject = Me.Name & " Submission"
        .HTMLBody = EmailBody
   End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

`"<font style='color:" & iif(len(Me.ttbBusinessUnit.Value)>0,"red","black") & ";'>" & UCase(Me.ttbBusinessUnit.Value) & "</font>"`

Comment: `red` and `black` should be quoted

Comment: @litelite not when using style `<font style='color:red'>test</font>`

Comment: True not in HTML, but definitely in VBA, since they are string literals.